# Passing recordset from C# code-beind into aspx page as Json

Tags: asp.net, json, client-side, json.net

On Page_Load I am getting data like

```
var products = BLL.Presenters.Products.GetAll();
```

It returns a list if about 10 products.

I would like to pass that LIST of products to the aspx page as json and then do some client-side stuff with the JSON object.

How can I pass JSON object from a recordset in code-behind TO the aspx page WITHOUT using a hidden field?

p.s We are already using Newtonsoft.Json library from other JSON stuff.

**- UPDATE -**

I was NOT able to get this working. I am now performing ajax call in JS (no code-behind) and getting the data needed.

Comment: Are you performing this using AJAX?

Comment: Does the JsonConvert.SerializeObject method not work for you?

Comment: No - we want to 'load' the json from code-behind into aspx page. We have the object as JSON in the code-behind, but how do we pass it to aspx page?

Comment: If you are not doing this using AJAX, what benefit do you expect to achieve by using JSON and "then do some client-side stuff"? Not arguing with you here, I just want to fully understand your use case.

Comment: @TheGreatCO: I think his question is how to pass the JSON to the page ... _without_ using a hidden field

Comment: The client-side 'stuff' is not the issue. The questions was How can I pass JSON object from a recordset in code-behind TO the aspx page?  thanks

Comment: @DavidKEgghead: I understand that, I was just trying to understand the _why_. Also, it is best to append the person's name to the comment so we know who you are responding to.

Comment: @ShaiCohen Not sure why you need to know what I will be doing with the JSON once its loaded, but here you go Once the objects are loading we will be using mustachejs for templating and formating the page for design.

Answer (score 1):

One way to pass a chunk of JSON to the page is to render it on the page directly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myData = <%= MyJsonString %>;
</script>
```

`MyJsonString` above is a property on your code behind class that contains the serialised object structure as a string of JSON data. It can be a method call if you prefer. Either way it must be able to return the JSON string before the page's render method gets called.

Obviously, you'll want to load it into an appropriate place for your application. If I'm doing this it is typically inside a small function, so it isn't global, that calls another function in a .js file somewhere that actually uses the data.

Also note the semi-colon after the string is rendered (although I'm lead to believe semi-colons are not strictly necessary in javaScript the old C/C++/C# programmer in me can't seem to give them up.)

And note that it is rendering with `<%= %>` so no HTML Encoding happens. This is important, otherwise the JSON string will get garbled and not make any sense inside the script block.

Finally, I've not done WebForms development for a couple of years so I might be rusty on some of the details - I hope the above makes sense and works for you.

**UPDATE**

I just remembered that WebForms has a "Literal" control, which is more likely what you want in order to keep with the convention. Something like this, perhaps:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myData = <asp:Literal runat="server" id="MyJsonLiteralControl" />;
</script>
```

In your code behind you set the Text of the literal control to be the JSON string that you have generated.

Comment: Thanks, we are trying to avoid just writing to the page. I was hoping to have the data within an 'js object' .. We have used a hidden field in the past. Seems sloppy ..

Comment: Your question only stated that you didn't want to put a hidden field on the page. If you don't want to write to the page at all then an AJAX call will be needed. I don't know what you mean by "js object" the JSON string will be interpreted as a javascript object when it parses the script block it is in.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view model of the object you want to send to your ASPX page.  This can be the exact same class as what is used in your normal runtime code.  Once you have this class, you can make use of AutoMapper to convert from one object class to another.  You can then add this newly mapped object to your return view.

```
var products = BLL.Presenters.Products.GetAll().ToList();
Mapper.CreateMap<Products, ProductsViewModel>()
var output = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Products>, List<ProductsViewModel>>(products);
return View("Index", output);
```

Your ViewModel class should look something like this.

```
public class ProductsViewModel
{
      public string Name {get; set;}
      public string UPC {get; set;}
      public double? Price {get; set;}
}
```

I assume you have more fields but this is just for illustration.  If you name the fields in your ViewModel class the same as in your main object class, AutoMapper will automagically convert from one type to another allowing you to just push the object through the ViewBag to your ASPX page.

Comment: @TheGreatOC : 'return View("Index", output); ' <-- not working.  We are NOT using MVC

Comment: @DavidKEgghead In that case, I believe you have to use some sort of AJAX request on page load to get the information, or embed it in the page using a hidden field.  I am unaware of any other method of sending the JSON to the page.